# Email feed on tags

Tags: support, tagging, notifications

Do we have Email feed on certain tags (such as one is interested in tag "algebraic geometry") here?

Phys.SE. has, it is quite nice. I cannot find it here. The "feeds" I found here is connected to Google Reader, or, to Feeder.

Thanks.

Comment: You can create [filters](http://stackexchange.com/filters/) based on tags. One of settings for a filter is whether you want email updates.

Comment: Dear Martin: thanks. It will still nice to have the feature I mentioned (as Phys SE), how difficult will it be to ask for setting this up?

Comment: Could you explain where it is no physics.stackexchange? (Screenshot, link, or at least more detailed description what you are talking about.) I have tried Physics.meta.SE, but I did not find much: [1](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5324/user-feed-and-question-feed), [2](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/751/email-notifications-for-updates/).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get regular emails with all the new questions from specific tag(s).

Go to math.stackexchange.com.  Click on "TAGS".  Search for the tag you want.  Hover over it, and wait for a box to pop up.  In the top-right corner of the box, next to rss, click "subscribe".  An email will be sent to your email to confirm your filter subscription.

Be aware that this sends you all questions for a tag, not just the unanswered ones, so you may have to search through them a bit if you want to write an answer.

Comment: Some related posts on meta.SO: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/93054/subscribe-to-interested-tags, http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72767/how-to-get-notification-via-email-whenever-new-questions-are-posted (And probably many other.)